# Zbar sdk not working for small screen android devices

Tags: android, barcode, barcode-scanner, zbar-sdk, zbar

I am having problems with using **Zbar** sdk for scanning qr codes in small screen mobiles of Android. ***The problem is that it couldnt scan the image.*** So I wanted to know all the **limitations of Zbar sdk** for Android. I tried to search it on internet and also on SO but no luck. Also I had my app with QR code scanning facility from Zbar sdk integrated and launched on Google Play. ***But for some devices (mostly small screen ones but not all) I was not able to find my app in Google Play market.*** What could be the reason ??

Please provide me with any docs or demos if anyone knows about this issues !!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. Try set the required value of android.hardware.camera.autofocus to false in manifest. I have Zbar tested in some Samsung phones without camera autofocus function, it works.

Comment: Are u talking about <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>..??